# error changedTouches[0].pageX - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I am not very knowledgeable about Javascript / jQuery and I am having a lot of trouble with a code.

It is for a carousel mobile that I did, but the Console displays "Uncaught TypeError: Can not read property '0' of undefined" in the part of "changedTouches [0] .pageX"

Can someone help me?

```
    CarouselCMS.prototype.mobileNav = function() {
    var that = this,
        diff = 0;
    this.$element.bind('touchstart', function(e){
        var initialX = e.changedTouches[0].pageX;
            initialY = e.changedTouches[0].pageY;
            dragging = true;
        that.$element.bind('touchmove', function(e) {
            if(Math.abs(initialY - e.changedTouches[0].pageY) < 10 || dragging == true) {
                if(Math.abs(initialX - e.changedTouches[0].pageX) > 10 ){
                    that.$container.css("transition", "none");
                    $('body').css('overflow-y','hidden');
                    dragging = true;
                    var translate = that.translateCalc();
                    diff = initialX - e.changedTouches[0].pageX;
                    translate -= diff;
                    that.$container.css("transform","translateX("+translate+"px)");
                    console.log('x');
                }
                e.preventDefault();
            }else {
                diff = 0;
                that.$element.unbind('touchmove');
            }
        });
    });
    this.$element.bind('touchend', function(){
        that.$element.unbind('touchmove');
        $('body').css('overflow-y','auto');
        that.$container.css("transition", "transform "+(that.options.speed/1000)+"s linear");
        if(diff > 100){
            that.next();
        }else if(diff < -100){
            that.prev();
        }
        diff = 0;
        that.moveSlider();
    });
}
```

Comment: e is an event. have you check chrome console and added breakpoints?

Comment: I checked the Chrome console, but I do not know how to add breakpoints :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jQuery Event object does not have a changedTouches property.

Instead use:

```
e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0]
```

Comment: I added "originalEvent" in the initialX and initialY variables. now the error appears "Uncaught ReferenceError: initialY is not defined"

Comment: Add `var` before `initialY = e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].pageY`.

Comment: var initialX = e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].pageX;
      initialY = e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].pageY;

Again "Uncaught ReferenceError: initialY is not defined"

Comment: You didnt add the var before initialY. again. :) Just add it in the beginning of the line, just like in `initialX`

Comment: Solved the problem! Thank you very much. Sorry for the problems, I'm still learning. ;)

Comment: No problem @DanielAndrade! Im glad to have helped! If my answer solved your question, please give it an upvote and accept it so that other users can learn from it.

Comment: Solved one problem, but another appeared. The touch that scrolls the vertical page (pageY) does not work. The page now scrolls horizontally (pageX). When I try to scroll the page down and up, I can not because it understands only the pageX

Comment: @DanielAndrade is this some browser issue? or do you think it's your code that caused it?

Comment: I tested Chrome and Firefox (mobile simulator) and Chrome directly on a smartphone

Comment: So youre saying the issue is that you cannot scroll up and down? This should have nothing to do with your code..?